# Theoretical: Most efficient way to implement a function that involves searching for multiple binary tree nodes

Tags: c, recursion, binary-search-tree

I'm trying to find the best way to implement a function that takes in a binary search tree and a specific phrase/word and returns a linked list.

So within my program, I have successfully created a binary search tree where each node contains a char *string, int value, and left/right struct pointers. Moreover, the nodes within this tree have been inserted based on the alphabet with strcmp. There are no duplicate strings within the tree.

My problem lies in the fact that the linked list, which needs to be returned, has to contain any tree node that matches the given search word OR holds the search word as a substring.

Based on this, I've been struggling to code any type of recursive function that is able to help find more than one node. Using ststr and a simple depth-first traversal will only return the first node that it finds. 
I have tried passing in a 2D array of some sort but it just gets really messy and annoying.

So is there any other way to tackle a problem like this?

I'm relatively new to C and programming in general so I'm just looking for any ideas or pseudocode that might help me out.

Thank you,

Comment: The problem is the word "substring". It means that a tree is of no use because you can't sort (build) the tree on an infinite number of viable substrings. A linked list could be better and you need to search it lineairly, testing all nodes.

Comment: That makes sense. I actually might have over analysed the problem that was given to me. Thank you.

Comment: If you still want to use your tree you have to iterate through the whole tree to be sure that you don't miss a potential match.

Comment: _"...char *string, int value, and left/right struct pointers..."_ - what is the int? the string's length?